# undefined symbol: vtable for SomeClass

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Just ran into these 2 Clang errors:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: vtable for HashFn
>>> referenced by hashFn.h:40 ......
HashFn::HashFn(int, bool)
```

And

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: vtable for HashFn
>>> referenced by hashFn.h:36 ......
HashFn::HashFn(HashFn const&)
```

hashFn.h -->

```
#ifndef HASHFN_H_
#define HASHFN_H_

#include "./base.h"

typedef uint64_t uint64Array[30];
static int precomputedArraySize = sizeof(uint64Array) / sizeof(uint64_t);

inline uint64_t customPow(uint64Array *precomputedPowers, bool usePrecomputed,
    uint64_t base, int exp) {
  if (usePrecomputed && exp < precomputedArraySize) {
    return (*precomputedPowers)[exp];
  }

  // TOOD: Optimization possible here when passed in toSize which is bigger
  // than precomputedArraySize, we can start from the value of the last
  // precomputed value.
  uint64_t result = 1;
  while (exp) {
    if (exp & 1)
      result *= base;
    exp >>= 1;
    base *= base;
  }
  return result;
}


// Functor for a hashing function
// Implements a Rabin fingerprint hash function
class HashFn {
 public:
  // Initialize a HashFn with the prime p which is used as the base of the Rabin
  // fingerprint algorithm
  explicit HashFn(int p, bool precompute = true) {
    this->p = p;
    this->precompute = precompute;
    if (precompute) {
      uint64_t result = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < precomputedArraySize; i++) {
        precomputedPowers[i] = result;
        result *= p;
      }
    }
  }
  //virtual ~HashFn(){}
  ~HashFn(){}

  virtual uint64_t operator()(const char *input, int len,
      unsigned char lastCharCode, uint64_t lastHash);

  virtual uint64_t operator()(const char *input, int len);

 private:
  int p;
  bool precompute;
  uint64Array precomputedPowers;
};

#endif  // HASHFN_H_
```

hashFn.cc -->

```
#include "hashFn.h"

uint64_t HashFn::operator()(const char *input, int len,
      unsigned char lastCharCode, uint64_t lastHash) {
    // See the abracadabra example:
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm
    return (lastHash - lastCharCode *
      customPow(&precomputedPowers, precompute, p, len - 1)) *
      p + input[len - 1];
  }

uint64_t HashFn::operator()(const char *input, int len) {
    uint64_t total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      total += input[i] *
        customPow(&precomputedPowers, precompute, p, len - i - 1);
    }
    return total;
  }
```

There is already a derived class from HashFn:

```
class HashFn2Byte : public HashFn {
 public:
  HashFn2Byte() : HashFn(0, false) {
  }

  uint64_t operator()(const char *input, int len,
      unsigned char lastCharCode, uint64_t lastHash) override;

  uint64_t operator()(const char *input, int len) override;
};
......
```

What went wrong? I can vaguely understand this has something to do with the virtual destructor but not sure why the vtable is undefined (if I define all declarations then vtable should be there automatically?).

Also, I'm now playing in Chromium so I don't know how would the fact all files are compiled into a "jumbo" object affect the results. The standalone version of this code ([a Node native module](https://github.com/bbondy/bloom-filter-cpp)) can compile and run normally.

Any input is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Did you provide definition for the `operator()` somewhere?

Comment: @Oliv Yes in the corresponding .cc file, with both signatures.

Comment: So this is not normal, clang should have defined the vtable in the object file where are defined the `operator()`. The fact that the destructor is virtual or not should not change that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: hmmm... I'm pretty new to C++ so there is no other clue on my mind either. Another thing is I'm in fact developing inside Chromium's codebase so all files in this directory are compiled and linked to a "jumbo" object file. Although I guess this shouldn't mattter at all?

Comment: Are you sure the code from your `.cc` file is being compiled and linked?

Comment: @PasserBy thanks for the heads-up! Have edited the question to include more code and context.

Comment: @G.M. I think so because compiler would look for .cc that corresponds to the header and compile/link it in my understanding?

Comment: No, the compiler won't do that.  That's up to whatever build system you're using.  So you need to check the output from your build to make sure the link command is correct.

Comment: Have you tried another compiler? gcc?

Comment: In most cases you should declare a virtual destructor if a class is polymorphic. This is not a hard rule and not declaring one does not cause missing vtable.